# Do these XSRF protections apply to RequestFactory as well?

Tags: java, gwt, csrf, requestfactory

I just read [this article on GWT RPC XSRF protection](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf), however am planning on writing a GWT app that takes advantage of the newer RequestFactory framework.

However, I don't see any RequestFactory-equivalent for this article, so I ask: do I need to worry about the attack vectors and necessary protections/precautions outlined in the article above if I'm using RequestFactory, or am I "immune"? Does anybody know of the RequestFactory-equivalent for these items? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not immune.

And I'm not aware of any equivalent for RequestFactory. You'd basically implement a `RequestTransport` on the client-side and a servlet filter on the server-side; but you'd have to find some mean of communicating the `XsrfToken` to the client (a dynamic host page comes to mind).